# Can I run arduino on Windows Embedded Compact 2013?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, robotics, software, windows

I'm actually working on a robotic project for which I'm planning to use arduino to drive the wheels.For this, I want to send signals from my Onboard embedded computer (which has Windows Embedded Compact 2013 OS) to arduino. Is this possible? If not possible, what are the other alternatives?

Comment: I think the title of the question is misleading. When you say "Can I run arduino" it would lead people believe you're asking whether you can run the Arduino IDE (which I don't know). But later you explain that you actually only want to send signals to the Arduino. This doesn't require the Arduino and is certainly possible. If you wanted a better answer you would need to explain what sort of communication you plan to use for these signals (serial, SPI, I2C, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

What OS is running on two different devices exchanging messages/signals, does not matter. What matters is the protocol.

You can use a lot of different ones:

- Wireless:

  - IR (infrared)
  - RF (radio), like 433 MHz, 2.4 GHz
  - WIFI (internet)
  - Bluetooth
- Wired

  - SPI
  - 'simple wires' / Wire library
  - Serial
  - USB (not on most Arduinos)

This list is not complete, just some examples.

Arduino supports all above (except USB fully), I don't know what Windows Embedded Compact OS supports.

Comment: Actually, the only thing an ordinary Arduino easily supports for interaction with a typical modern PC *is* USB.  That will present on both ends as a serial port, but in terms of what you connect with a cable, it is USB.

Comment: strictly speaking the answer is correct, but would be clearer if it was changed to say Serial + USB Serial as the 3rd option and Native USB (not on most arduinos) as the 4th